# How to sort an array based on object property in the same order of another array object property in node js

Tags: node.js, sorting

The following is Array 1

```
[ { _id: 5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9,
messages: [ "A", "B", "C" ] },

{ _id: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
messages: [ "D" , "E", "F"] } ]
```

The following is Array 2

```
[ { users: [ 'T' ],
ids: [ '5e79fdf9a783ce06caa6c7f8' ],
_id: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
time: 2020-03-25T22:42:54.017Z,
__v: 0 },


{ users: [ 'X' ],
ids: [ '5e76615566053a1613b61275' ],
_id: 5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9,
time: 2020-03-25T20:11:53.758Z,
__v: 0 } ]
```

I want to sort Array1 based on Array2 _id property.  For example, I want my final result to look like the following
For Array 1

```
{ _id: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
messages: [ "D" , "E", "F"] } ]

[ { _id: 5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9,
messages: [ "A", "B", "C" ] },
```

while Array2 will remain as following:

```
 [ { users: [ 'T' ],
ids: [ '5e79fdf9a783ce06caa6c7f8' ],
_id: 5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12,
time: 2020-03-25T22:42:54.017Z,
__v: 0 },


{ users: [ 'X' ],
ids: [ '5e76615566053a1613b61275' ],
_id: 5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9,
time: 2020-03-25T20:11:53.758Z,
__v: 0 } ]
```

I tried to do the following but it doesn't work

```
 const test = Array1.sort(function(a,b){
        return Array2.indexOf(a._id) - Array2.indexOf(b._id)
 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

Your code doesn't work because you are trying to find an `_id` inside the `Array2`, but the Array was not structured the way you are trying to use.

The way it is: `Array[object{_id}]`
The way you are trying to use: `Array[_id]`

---

---

#### Solution

What you need is a function that finds an object inside the array based on its `_id` property and returns its index:

```js
// You can create a new function to the Array class (Array.prototype)
// Returns the index of the element which _id equals myID
Array.prototype.indexOfMyID = function(myID){
    let index = this.findIndex(function(element){
        if(element._id === myID){
            return true;
        }
    });
    return index;
}
```

Now you can use that function as a built-in function from Array class

```js
const test = Array1.sort(function(a, b){
    return Array2.indexOfMyID(a._id) - Array2.indexOfMyID(b._id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just map array2 to get a list of ids and then compare the order of that instead.

```js
const arr1 = [ 
  { 
    _id: '5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9', 
    messages: [ "A", "B", "C" ] 
  },
  { 
    _id: '5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12', 
    messages: [ "D" , "E", "F"]
  }
];

const arr2 = [
  { 
    users: [ 'T' ], 
    ids: [ '5e79fdf9a783ce06caa6c7f8' ], 
    _id: '5e7ba776c55fc40b216b0d12', 
    time: '2020-03-25T22:42:54.017Z', 
    __v: 0
  },
  { users: [ 'X' ],
    ids: [ '5e76615566053a1613b61275' ],
    _id: '5e7bb66d99aa010ca9bfeed9',
    time: '2020-03-25T20:11:53.758Z',
    __v: 0
  }
];

const ids = arr2.map(item => item._id);
const result = arr1.sort((a, b) => ids.indexOf(a._id) - ids.indexOf(b._id));
console.log(result);
```